# Slice in repository `The return type is incompatible with PagingAndSortingRepository`

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have create findAll function with return type Slice then got this error:
`The return type is incompatible with PagingAndSortingRepository<Book,Long>.findAll(Pageable)`
Here is my code in repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Slice;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Book> {
    Slice<Book> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: That method is already available in the `JpaRepository` and returns a `Page` you cannot redifine it with another return type and you don't actually need it because it is already there.

Comment: I got it. Idk why I created when It's already there. Thank you @M.Deinum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from [M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) in comment

> That method is already available in the JpaRepository and returns a Page you >cannot redifine it with another return type and you don't actually need it >because it is already there.

Answer (score -1):

" `List<BookingSlip> findAll(Pageable pageable);`" i have used this statement, then got error - "   - The return type is incompatible with `PagingAndSortingRepository<BookingSlip,Long>.findAll(Pageable)`
"      then i have used " `Page<BookingSlip> findAll(Pageable pageable);`"   and my problem resolved correctly.